# Can I run a 120v/15amp 120 watt Hard Wire towel rack connection to the existing GFCI within the same bathroom

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci

Can I  run a 120volt 120 watt  Hard Wire towel rack connection to an existing GFCI with-in the same bathroom ?

Comment: Is it 15 amps (1800 watts)? Or is it 120 watts (1 amp)?

Comment: sorry typo its 1200 watts

Comment: originally I had  asked the question for the following :

Comment: Originally I had  asked the question for the following : Towel rack  with the following parameters   15amp //120 Watts  then for some reason the question was asked Is it 120 or 1200 watt  rechecking this it is 120 watts not 1200 . Is the current rating for this device  1Watt@80%=0.8 watts  ? If so would this be allowed ?

Comment: That's a different kettle of fish, then. Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, the towel rack can be on a circuit with receptacles

Because it will amount to less than 50%  of total circuit capacity.  You cannot have receptacles on a circuit where more than half is *provisioned* (reserved) for fixed loads.

This heater has a nameplate of 120 watts, which is 1 amps.  Now, normally a heater is defined as a *continuous load*.  So we must *provision* 125% of that, or 150 watts (1.25 amps).*

The capacity of a 15A circuit is 1800W (half is 900W). The capacity of a 20A circuit is 2400W (half is 1200W).  Even with the 125% derate, this device is nowhere near half.

Therefore it can share the circuit with other fixed loads and receptacles, as long as all the fixed loads together total less than half circuit capacity.

---

* This 125% is exactly the same thing as the "80% derate" you hear about for continuous loads, just we're applying it to the load instead of the circuit. We must do it this way because it would mix with other loads that are not continuous.

Answer (score 0):

I have this exact setup at my house. I did pull a second circuit after my wife tripped the breaker a few times, if you turn the bar off there will be no problems (mine has a switch on the bottom of one of the uprights) but with the rack on and a hair dryer it would trip the breaker when she would forget to turn it off. Warm towels are so nice getting out of the shower.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too .  Haidryer + Curling Iron  overload  Thanks  I will run an additional  GFCI to the Hardwired toel rack .

Comment: Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.